# How I can control AsyncStorage with Redux Slice in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, asyncstorage

I'm new to Redux (not React-Native) and The most straightforward way I found to use Redux is to use it with the `createSlice` function.
Here is the slice -

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    cart: null
}

const Slice = createSlice({
    name: 'userAuth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setLogin: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoggedIn = action.payload.isLoggedIn;
            AsyncStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", JSON.stringify(state.isLoggedIn));
        },
        setLogout: (state) => {
            state.isLoggedIn = false;
            AsyncStorage.clear();
        },
        setCart: (state, action) => {
            state.cart = action.payload.cart;
            AsyncStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(action.payload.cart));
        },
        startUp: (state, action) => {
            state.cart = action.payload.cart;
            state.isLoggedIn = action.payload.isLoggedIn;
        }
    }
});


export const { setLogin, setLogout, setCart, startUp } = Slice.actions;

export const selectIsLoggedIn = (state) => state.userAuth.isLoggedIn;
export const selectCart = (state) => state.userAuth.cart;

export default Slice.reducer;
```

I'm using the `useDispatch` hook for updating the state.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

dispatch(setCart({cart: cartObj}));
```

But it leads me to an error-

```
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
onChange
http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:191470:48
generatorResume@[native code]
asyncGeneratorStep@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:25072:26
_next@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:25094:29
http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:25101:14
tryCallTwo@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:30613:9
doResolve@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:30777:25
Promise@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:30636:14
http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:25090:25
onChange@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:191487:33
http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:191758:24
generatorResume@[native code]
asyncGeneratorStep@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:25072:26
_next@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:25094:29
tryCallOne@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:30604:16
http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:30705:27
http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:31784:26
_callTimer@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:31684:17
_callReactNativeMicrotasksPass@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:31719:17
callReactNativeMicrotasks@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:31926:44
__callReactNativeMicrotasks@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:24002:46
http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:23781:45
__guard@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:23985:15
flushedQueue@http://192.168.0.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:23780:21
flushedQueue@[native code]
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

I'm using Expo-CLI on Ubuntu 22.04.
Please tell me the right way to do this.

Comment: Is there any onChange event , this cause the issue

Comment: Yes, I'm updating the state with onChange event in react-native-input-spinner package.

Comment: Try to avoid it for a while and try again. I think problem lies with that

Comment: Mishen, You are right. When I use the reducer outside onChange function, It works fine. So, Can you tell me how I can change the item quantity in cart state?

Answer (score 2):

setting data  into the asyncStorage is asynchronous.
Under no circonstances you should not run an asynchronous  value into reducer(should 100% synchronus). instead move the asyncStorage code to your api request function,then set it into asyncStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Redux Persist to perform state management with Async Storage.
Check this out for further instructions.

https://blog.logrocket.com/use-redux-persist-react-native/

Comment: I already checked the link but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap AsyncStorage functions with async/await

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).